# Better way to remesh from a solidworks file?

Tags: modeling

I was wondering if someone had some advice for me. I'd say im intermediate with blender after being on and off with it for 6 years. I am not currently using 2.8 but thats a different story. I work at a watch company as a Videographer and I thought about putting some 3d animations into the mix. I saw a tutorial on youtube that showed a way to import an STL file into blender but the mesh is really gross. I get the STL's directly from our watch designiners who use solidworks. I have been joining verticies and removing doubles while also using "tris to quads" and it cleans it up pretty good but theres still work to be done.

My plan is to simplify the meshes so that mapping looks correct for shaders and then I want to be able to import into element 3d in after effects for quick simple animations of say just a watch spinning in circles and yes I do know how to animate the hands on the watch.

I am just trying to see if theres a much faster easier way to keep the mesh the way it is but making the topology less... Dynamic? Making the mesh just quads

So heres what I have figured out so far. 
-joining verticies and removing doubles
-tris to quads
-shrinkwrap modifier
-mirror modifier (most of the watch parts are symmetrical)

The shrink wrap seems to work a little bit but on some more complex curves, it tends to get lost. For instance trying to shrink wrap from the watches strap lug holder...um... thingy to the actual case itself.

are there some other quicker better methods to remesh/ retopologize an existing object other than what I mentioned or is it basically what im already doing.

just to be clear I will be using subsurf mod once I have a better mesh

heres the youtube video I watched for solidworks to blender. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1nlNYSxvMs&t=318s

[image: front of watch dial]

[image: front of dial object mode]

[image: back of case edit mode]

[image: back of case object mode]

Comment: your question is a bit too broad, maybe share just one  part of your mesh to see how we could simplify it

Comment: There is a paid add-on *Open VDB remesher* https://gumroad.com/l/jqLNZ
Have not used it, but looks interesting